# Broadcom wireless doesn't work on an HP Mini 110 1199EA under Wubi install

Tags: wireless, wubi, broadcom

I used the Windows install for Ubuntu today, it all installed easily and automatically but I could not go on the Internet. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

I *think* it was "Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS" but I'm not sure, I did it today, 8th of June 2012. I am using the HP Mini 110 1199EA.

It says 'firmware not found' or something like that. What is firmware and why isn't it found?  My wireless device seems to be called "Broadcom 802.11b/g WLAN" does that make any sense?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: ^^^ this will get us the exact wireless model, which would be usefu.

Answer (score 3):

> My wireless device seems to be called "Broadcom 802.11b/g WLAN" does that make any sense?

Yes. You need to install drivers for it, in this manner:

- Connect your netbook to a *wired* connection (your router/ethernet)
- Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`
- Type `sudo apt-get update`
- Type `sudo apt-get install b43-cutter firmware-b43-installer -y`
- Exit, reboot and give it 30 seconds or so...you should hopefully see the "Wireless Networks Detected" popup.
- If you don't have a way of getting the wired connection, please add a comment and I'll include a way using a USB stick.

Comment: Official page and docs [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Ubuntu.2FDebian).

Comment: "If you don't have a way of getting the wired connection, please add a comment and I'll include a way using a USB stick." - that would be nice, thanks!